# Unable to use "as JSON" after upgrading to grails 2.1.1 from grails 1.3.4

Tags: json, grails-2.0

I'm in the process of upgrading a grails plugin from 1.3.4 to grails 2.1.1. After upgrading I now have an integration test that fails that was not failing before. It fails on using the "as JSON" (grails.converters.JSON).

```
    @Test
public void testConvertCollectionOfEnvironmentSettingsToJSON() {
    EnvironmentSetting setting = configurationService.getEnvironmentSetting('ENFORCE_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_RULE')

    def jsonSetting = setting as JSON //exception thrown here
    def s = jsonSetting as String

    assertNotNull jsonSetting
}
```

The exception and stacktrace:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.company.ipsvc.configuration.domain.EnvironmentSettingAllRevs@48c12420' with class 'com.company.ipsvc.configuration.domain.EnvironmentSettingAllRevs' to class 'grails.converters.JSON'
at com.company.ipsvc.configuration.converter.json.basic.BasicEnvironmentSettingJSONIntegrationTests.testConvertCollectionOfEnvironmentSettingsToJSON(BasicEnvironmentSettingJSONIntegrationTests.groovy:28)
```

I am able to use encodeAsJSON() successfully. I also have the same issue with as XML.

Comment: I found out that I only have the issue when I'm using hibernate mapping xml files and don't put the class in the domain folder but in src/groovy folder. I need to configure the domain class using hibernate mapping files, so this only helps me narrow the issue down.

Grails does treat my class as a domain class and I compared the methods generated between a domain class inside the domain folder and one outside using hibernate mapping files and the only method that is not generated by the one outside the domain folder is "autowireDomain"

Comment: I found this bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9089 that looks like it might be related, but no solution.

Comment: No solution yet, but logged a bug. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9513

Answer (score 5):

I think converters (`as JSON` syntax) will only work on domain objects and collections by default.

To convert arbitrary objects you should use the `encodeAsJSON()` converter, I believe. Or use an object marshaller, where you tell the converter how to deal with your object.

The docs aren't very clear on this though..

See:

- http://grails.org/Converters+Reference (object marshalling section at bottom)
- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html

But I note that http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/converters/JSON.html#JSON%28java.lang.Object%29 says that the object converts POGOs.. Maybe it means if you have a marshaller?

I did find this reference too:

> Notice that the ‘as’ operator is not overloaded for plain objects ...
>
> Domain objects can use the ‘as’ operator to cast an object to JSON, the same as a collection. So unlike POGOs, where they must be massaged into a list or have encodeAsJSON explictly called ...
>
> http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/08/rendering-json-in-grails-part-2-plain-old-groovy-objects-and-domain-objects/

Which seems to describe the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is a domain object and it worked on v 1.3.4.

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't be that surprised if it stopped working from the 1 > 2 upgrade, but since it's a domain object that is puzzling!

Comment: related:  http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6222  "Default JSON ObjectMarshallers should be configured when Grails ApplicationContext does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

For non-Domain objects, we found that this would crop up when running tests... the solution for us was to use new JSON:

```
render new JSON( obj )
```

This would allow the test to work, and the code does the same thing (essentially)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue that broke unit test using grails 2.2.1  . At issue was a straight `obj as JSON` conversion attempt. But this was interpreted as type casting instead.

The workaround is to stuff your obj to be converted into a map like this `[data:obj] as JSON`